# Flutter : How to disable a widget for a fix time

Tags: flutter

I have checkbox widget that I would like to hide for 24 hours after the user click it. I want to prevent then from continuously clicking on the the button.

How are can I do this in Flutter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences lib to store timestamp and then use ternary conditional operator to show or hide your button
`yourBool ? RadioButton() : SizedBox()...`